# body_filter_by_lua_block code to replace URL to Another URL for All Mime Type

Tags: nginx, lua, openresty

I'm noob in openresty lua coding,
I want to change string to another string...

especialy, url to another url like this :
https://example.com to https://example.org using body_filter_by_lua_block {},

before I use nginx sub_filter, but not all mime type changed, although I have

```
sub_filter_once off;
sub_filter_types *;
sub_filter "https://example.com/" "https://example.org/";
```

but not all url changed...

Any one can help me solve the problem...
your help greatly appreciate...

Comment: *"not all mime type changed"* ...I believe it might be helpful if you could be more specific about what works and what doesn't.

Comment: don't know...
In one of website, it can change, html and js and css...
another website, it can't change,,,,

Comment: You're trying to solve this with Lua or with regular nginx directives?

What if your location pattern does not match and therefore the filter does not apply?

Could you gives us more context on what you're trying to achieve or a slightly longer example?

Comment: @Rok example,
I want to replace all related url that point to fortune.com ...
when it's first load in browser it via our domain fortune.club ....

then when we click url/link in the website, it goes to fortune.com not via us, fortune.club....

do you have an idea? how to accomplished it?

I'm try to use body_filter_by_lua_block {}, but not much have a background in lua language